Can Ubuntu 20.04 update alone to 22.04?
I'm new to this but a problem just occurred to me, I have several computers with Ubuntu 20.04, why this version? basically for compatibility of applications that are already in production. Just this weekend, 4 of them were updated to Ubuntu 22.04, which completely affected the operation of the applications installed on these computers. My question regarding that is, does the operating system update require human interaction to be done or can Ubuntu update forcibly after a while? If so, how can I disable this possibility and completely prevent Ubuntu from changing its version again? I appreciate any suggestion or clarification. (Google Translate) srry.

Ubuntu does not upgrade to a new major version such as 20.04 to 22.04 without human interaction. Someone has to click a button or type a command. Then they have to click the "Continue" button.

On a stock install of Ubuntu, a human must initiate the release-upgrade process to prevent precisely the issues you encountered. It cannot be automatically initiated. However, many humans are also smart enough to haywire, disable, override, or ignore that protection. Whoever did it might be too embarrassed to admit their mistake.

You have absolute control.
Go to Software & Updates

Then navigate down to Notify me of a new Ubuntu version use the drop down and select Never

if that answered your question, please consider accepting it. Thanks a lot.

There is way. Open a terminal and run:
sudo systemctl stop unattended-upgrades.service
sudo systemctl disable unattended-upgrades.service
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily-upgrade.service
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.service

And there is a link to help you how to find  terminal

Does it block package updates and/or distro updates to new releases?

None of these have anything to do with release upgrades.
